# three.js: mesh1.position.set is not a function

Tags: three.js

I have tried everything to set the position of my newly minted `mesh1` Mesh object. The `mesh1.position` property is read only, `mesh1.setPosition` doesn't exist and neither do `mesh1.position.set`. This is my current code:

```
var plane1 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 20, 5, 5);
var mesh1 = utils_misc.mesher(plane1, intersection, 0xffffff, "", false, true, false);
```

The relevant parts of the mesher function looks like this:

```
function mesher ( aGeometry, position, color, name, woodTexture, doubleSided, debug ) {
// ...
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(aGeometry, material);
mesh.position.set = position;
mesh.name = name;
mesh.callback = function() { makeDOMelements.info.innerHTML = name; };
makeScene.scene.add( mesh );
}
```

I have also tried this:

```
mesh1.position.set(intersection.x, intersection.y, intersection.z);
```

How do the cool guys set their positions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would not work:

```
mesh.position.set = position;
```

you need to do

```
mesh.position.copy( position );
```

but

```
mesh1.position.set(intersection.x, intersection.y, intersection.z);
```

should have worked as long as `mesh1` is of type `Object3D`